# using xpages with twitter4j to get access token on server

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, twitter4j

I am using twitter4j to show some tweets on my webpage. The code works fine when I am running it locally. If I put it on the server I got an error.

The code looks like

```
Twitter twitter = TwitterFactory.getSingleton();
twitter.setOAuthConsumer(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
```

**error:**

```
java.lang.AssertionError: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
twitter4j.TwitterFactory.(TwitterFactory.java:76)
java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:200)
de.workm.java.xc.twitter11.TwitterOAuthCredentials.getRequestURL(TwitterOAuthCredentials.java:167)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
com.ibm.jscript.types.JavaAccessObject.call(JavaAccessObject.java:321)
com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSObject.call(FBSObject.java:161)
com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTCall.interpret(ASTCall.java:197)
com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTVariableDecl.interpret(ASTVariableDecl.java:82)
com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpret(ASTProgram.java:119)
com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpretEx(ASTProgram.java:139)
com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression._interpretExpression(JSExpression.java:435)
com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.access$1(JSExpression.java:424)
com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression$2.run(JSExpression.java:414)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:310)
com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.interpretExpression(JSExpression.java:410)
com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.evaluateValue(JSExpression.java:251)
com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.evaluateValue(JSExpression.java:234)
com.ibm.xsp.javascript.JavaScriptInterpreter.interpret(JavaScriptInterpreter.java:222)
com.ibm.xsp.binding.javascript.JavaScriptMethodBinding.invoke(JavaScriptMethodBinding.java:111)
com.ibm.xsp.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:60)
javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:324)
```

Thanks
Armin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class uses reflection which is not allowed for [normal mortal code](http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-8JYAT5). You need up either put it into a plugin or [elevate permissions](http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-97WPR9)

Comment: Hi Stephan, I found your side before and changed the policy file with no effect. There is no security warning/error in the error message, so I thought it should be something different.

Comment: Ok, after writing my first comment I rembered that I did some changes a  long time ago with my local policy. But there I took the 'complete' version. grant{
 permission java.security.AllPermission;
}; Ok, I know this is very bad style ;) I tried this solution for testing on the server an it worked. So I have 'only' an issue with the syntax to grant only access for a special application. Thanks